# error 2068 (hy000): load data local infile file request rejected due to restrictions on access. windows

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer un cargue masivo de datos pero presento este error error 2068 (hy000): load data local infile file request rejected due to restrictions on access.
El local_infile es igual a ON y el OPT_LOCAL_INFILE es igual a 1. Pero presenta el mismo error si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agredeceria.
La version de MySQL es la 8.0.25

Comment: Muestra el comando que estas usando para importar

Comment: `mysql> load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\Laura\\Documents\\Libro1.csv' into table variables_p  fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'  lines terminated by '\r\n';`

Comment: Da clic en [edit] y agrega el comando a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿El usuario tiene permisos para leer el archivo? El mensaje de error parece indicar que no. Revisa los permisos del archivo `Libro1.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Este error es debido a restricciones de acceso para cargas desde archivos, indicas que `local_infile` es igual a `ON` entonces ya solo inicia sesión en MySQL de esta forma:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p
```

Ya con la sesión iniciada puedes realizar tu carga

```
load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\Laura\\Documents\\Libro1.csv'
into table variables_p
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

Comment: ya logre solucionar el error.
En la sentencia de load borre el local y en archivo my.ini lo configure para que la ruta quedara global.
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hola @MR Dev Buenos días. Yo tengo el mismo problema que Laura y también lo solucione como has dicho, pero una pregunta ¿Se podría configurar mysql para no tener que entrar como tú has puesto? Osea entrar -h localhost -u root -p

Comment: @CarlosVallDeSego Primero revisa si no está habilitado con la consulta `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';`, para habilitarlo lo haces con la consulta  `SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;`

Comment: Hola @MR Dev poniendo "SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;" cada vez que reinicio o apago el servidor se elimina el 'SET' y hay que volver a setearlo. Ademas  de esa forma cada vez que entro en mysql tengo que entrar asi: "mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p". Lo que quería era configurar los archivos para entrar en modo normal sin "-infile=1"